# Find first non-consecutive array element using Google Sheets Filter

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula

I have to make this work in a (always sorted) array that results from splitting a delimited string of sorted whole numbers. Concretely, if my cell contains `"1,2,3,5"` I need a formula to evaluate to `4`. A beneficial side-effect would be to find an implementation that would give the last-number+1, if the original array had only consecutive numbers, i.e., applying the formula to `"1,2,3,4,5"` would evaluate to `6`.

My approach has been to generate a new array that is a perfect sequence  and compare it with my original array, to find the first element where the two arrays are not equal.
Creating a perfect sequence of the array like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNT(arr),1,MIN(arr),1))
```

So all that would be left to do is compare arr with the sequence above to find the first element that differed, something like:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(arr;MATCH(arr;  transpose(sequence(count(arr),1,min(arr),1)) 
 ;0))))
```

Sadly, what I have above is not correctly "short-circuiting" at the first non equal value of the arrays. Is COUNTIF the way to go?

If my previous step gets me the index of the element instead of the value, then what remains is to get the value at that index:

```
INDEX( arr, 1, counta(iferror(filter(arr;match(arr1;  transpose(sequence(count(arr),1,min(arr),1)) 
 ;0)))) )
```

Is there a more straight-forward way get the first non-consecutive element? A way that does not involve actual ranges in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I realized that set-subtracting (i.e. set difference) the original array from the generated sequence always gives me the first missing number.
So my final formula to handle this and the case where all numbers are in sequence is this:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNT(SPLIT(G7," ")),1,LEFT(G7,4),1)), ISERROR(MATCH(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNT(split(G7," ")),1,LEFT(G7,4),1)),SPLIT(G7, " "),False))),1,1),RIGHT(G7,4)+1) )
```

I'm sure there is a better, more concise answer, but this does the job.